# Ovalization of a pvc pipe under a weight

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, material-science, fiber-optics, optical-materials

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but it came up in one of my physics courses so here goes.

I want to measure a weight using a Fiber Bragg Grating optic cable. Someone suggested the following idea to me: pull the cable through some holes on opposite sides of a pvc pipe, make sure it's nice and straight, and glue it in place. So if you look at the front of the pipe it should look something like this inside:
[image]

Now, if you were to apply a downward force a the top of this pipe it would deform, or ovalize, compressing along the vertical axis and stretching along the horizontal axis. The cable would be stretched as well, and due to the fiber bragg grating you could measure how much it stretched with some light and measuring equipment.

The problem is that I have no idea how to model the relation between the force on top and the change in length of the cable. I have searched endlessly online, but this seems to be a largely unexplored problem. Or perhaps I'm just missing something obvious. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

Comment: Perhaps the idea is that you calibrate the apparatus using known weights. This is more reliable than making a mathematical model of unknown accuracy based on the reported elastic properties of PVC. The physical properties of PVC vary depending the details of the manufacturing process.

Comment: What is I used a steel pipe instead? Would the same caveat apply?

Comment: Steel is an alloy of variable composition and variable micro-structure (depending on heat treatment) so again the properties vary although less so than with PVC. If your purpose is to do a calculation for the fun of it then it is irrelevant what the material is; the request for a calculation might be closed as a homework-and-exercises question. If your purpose is to build a practical measuring device then calibration is essential - as is periodical re-calibration to ensure that the relation between inputs and outputs has not changed..

Comment: Besides, for the same dimensions steel is much stiffer so it will be less suitable for measuring small weights and less sensitive to small differences.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. It is just a project assignment for school, though we are supposed to build a working proof-of-concept model. I guess we won't escape having to calibrate in any case.

Comment: No you won't escape the need for calibration. And as a school project you are probably expected to provide some theory in your report, to compare with experimental results. The theory could relate either to Fibre Bragg Gratings or to the mechanical properties of PVC - or possibly both. Which you focus on depends on whether this is an optics project or a mechanics project. I shall see what I can do to help you with the latter, which is what you are asking about here.